# Solving Fourier transform by using the Fourier Table

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I would like to calculate the Fourier transform of the signal x(t) without using the development integral. 
In some examples, you can use the Fourier table by "selective" looking, to calculate the Fourier transform. 
Here I have an example with x(t). But unfortunately I find no way to convert this with the Fourier table.

$$x(t)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle
 cos\left( \frac { 2\pi  }{ T } t \right) -0.5,\left| t \right| \le T/4 \\
  -0.5,\left| t \right| >T/4
\end{cases}$$

If someone has a Idea for me, that would be great! Thanks

Comment: Hint: write $x(t) = (\cos(2\pi t/T) - 0.5) \chi_{|t|\leq T/4} - 0.5 \chi_{|t| > T/4} = (A-0.5)\chi_{B} -0.5 \chi_{B^c}$. By linearity of the Fourier transfor
$$ \mathcal{F}(x(t)) =  \mathcal{F}((A-0.5)\chi_{B}) - 0.5 \mathcal{F}(\chi_{B^c}) = \big(\mathcal{F}(A) -0.5 \mathcal{F}(1)\big)\star \mathcal{F}(\chi_{B}) - 0.5 \mathcal{F}(\chi_{B^c}). $$